# cordova file transfer plugin not working in ios simulator

Tags: ios, cordova, ios-simulator, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use the camera plugin and file transfer on my project. They work fine on android but when I tested on ios simulator, I'm getting an empty request body on the server when I try to upload a photo using the cordova file transfer plugin.

In the code below, the `photo_url` is the response that I get from the camera plugin. This contains the full path of the photo that I selected from the gallery. Here's the value that I got when I used `console.log`:

```
file:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/87045654-FB0C-40E8-97A8-5634FC2D05E7/data/Containers/Data/Application/E0810976-FF0F-43E2-BC15-3EFDD93D61C4/tmp/cdv_photo_010.jpg
```

Here's the code:

```
 var options = new FileUploadOptions();
      options.fileKey = 'file';
      options.fileName = photo_url.substr(photo_url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).split('?')[0];
      options.mimeType = 'image/jpeg';
      options.params = params;

      var ft = new FileTransfer();
      ft.upload(
        photo_url, me.upload_url + path + '/photo/upload', 
        function(result){
          console.log('success');
          console.log(result);
        },
        function(err){
          console.log('error');
          console.log(err);
        }, 
        options
      );
```

The value for `options.fileName` is: `cdv_photo_010.jpg`.

I tried looking for solutions and I found the following:

```
options.headers = {
 Connection: "close"
};

options.chunkedMode = false;
```

I applied it to my existing code but it still didn't work. The request body that I'm getting in the server is still an empty object.

I'm using an express server and  [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) to handle file uploads.

Here's the code on the server:

```
var multer_options = { 
    dest: './public/uploads',
    fileSize: '',
    fields: 10,
    files: 1,
    rename: function(fieldname, filename){
        return random.string(30) + '-' + Date.now();
    },
    changeDest: function(original_dest, req, res){

        console.log('org dest:');
        console.log(original_dest);

        console.log('request body: ');
        console.log(req.body);

        var j = JSON.parse(req.body);
        console.log('parsed body: ');
        console.log(j);

        var request_data = req.body.request_data;
        console.log('request data: ');
        console.log(request_data);
        var dest = original_dest + '/' + request_data.upload_path;

        console.log('upload path: ');
        console.log(request_data.upload_path);

        console.log('dest: ');
        console.log(dest);

        var stat = null;

        try{
            stat = fs.statSync(dest);
        }catch(err){
            fs.mkdirSync(dest);
        }

        if(stat && !stat.isDirectory()){
            throw new Error('Directory cannot be created because an inode of a different type exists at "' + dest + '"');
        }

        return dest;
    }
};
```

Multer already handles the file upload, so all I have to do is write the code for instructing multer to change the destination directory, which is what I have above. When uploading files in android, it works fine. I get values for the request body. But on ios its empty. So I think the problem is either with ios simulator or the file transfer plugin has issues when working with ios simulator.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. Could you solve it?

Comment: I gave up trying to use the file URL and used the data URI instead. So in the camera plugin I just get the data URI and then pass that to the file transfer plugin.

Comment: @Kyokasuigetsu - solution below

Answer (score 0):

## File Upload: Cordova File Transfer Plugin + ExpressJs Multer

The solution below lets me take a photo with the iPhone camera, and then uploads the photo to a NodeJS server.

*@Kyokasuigetsu* - almost gave up on FILE_URI with Cordova's File Transfer Plugin as well!

---

> Notice that `options.fileKey = 'myPhoto'` and
> `upload.single('myPhoto')` should have the same value. It refers to the field name for the file upload form.
>
> ```
> <!-- Upload a single file -->
> <form>  
>   <input type="file" name="myPhoto" />
> </form>
> ```

#### Install needed plugins and modules (from console)

`> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer;`
`> npm install express multer --save;`

#### Cordova (native_app.js)

```
function uploadPhoto(fileUri) {
  // file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/
  // .../tmp/cdv_photo.jpg
  console.log("fileUri:", fileUri);

  var options, request;

  options = new FileUploadOptions();
  // The name 'fileKey' is confusing; it should be 'fieldname'
  options.fileKey = 'myPhoto';
  // fileName: 'cdv_photo.jpg';
  options.fileName =
    fileUri.substr(fileUri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

  request = new FileTransfer();
  request.upload(
    fileUri,
    encodeURI('http://localhost:8080/photos'),
    function success(response) {
      console.log("Success: Photo uploaded to server!");
    },
    function error(response) {
      console.log("Error: Photo not uploaded to server!");
    },
    options
  );
}

function capturePhoto(callback) {

  navigator.camera.getPicture(
    function success(fileUri) {
      callback(fileUri);
    },
    function error() {},
    { // camera options
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }
  );

}

function captureAndUploadPhoto() {
  capturePhoto(function (fileUrl) {
    uploadPhoto(fileUrl);
  });
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", captureAndUploadPhoto, false);
```

#### NodeJs / ExpressJs (server_app.js)

```
var express, application, multer, upload;

express = require('express');
application = express();
multer  = require('multer');
upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/'}).single('myPhoto');

application.get('/photos', upload, function (request, response) {
  console.log(response.file);
  response.status(204).end();
});

application.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Example application listening on port 8080!');
});
```